# React Component and CSSTransitionGroup

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

early days with Facebook ReactJS. Simple CSS fade-in transition. It works as expected with ReactJS v0.5.1. It doesn't with v11.1, v12.0, v12.1. Here's the CSS and JSX:

CSS

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
```

JSX for ReactJS v12.1

```
/**@jsx React.DOM*/

var ReactTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ReactTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
          <h1>Hello world</h1>      
      </ReactTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
```

Here's the list of Codepens:

- v0.5.1 http://codepen.io/lanceschi/pen/ByjGPW
- v0.11.1 http://codepen.io/lanceschi/pen/LEGXgP
- v0.12.0 http://codepen.io/lanceschi/pen/ByjGOR
- v0.12.1 http://codepen.io/lanceschi/pen/YPwROy

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,
Luca

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like `CSSTransitionGroup` used to animate on initial mount, but it doesn't any more as of React v0.8.0 or so. See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1304 for a bit more info.

One solution is to simply mount the `<h1>` after `<HelloWorld>` is mounted, like so:

```
/**@jsx React.DOM*/

var ReactTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { mounted: false };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setState({ mounted: true });
  },
  render: function() {
    var child = this.state.mounted ?
      <h1>Hello world</h1> :
      null;

    return (
      <ReactTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
        {child}
      </ReactTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
```

**Live example**: http://codepen.io/peterjmag/pen/wBMRPX

Note that `CSSTransitionGroup` is intended for transitioning child components as they're dynamically added, removed, and replaced, not necessarily for animating them on initial render. Play around with [this TodoList Codepen](http://codepen.io/peterjmag/pen/KwVbyJ) (adapted from [this example in the React docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#getting-started)) to see what I mean. The list items fade in and out as they're added and removed, but they don't fade in on the initial render.

**EDIT**: A new "appear" transition phase has been introduced recently to allow for animation-on-mount effects. See https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/2512 for details. (The commit has already been merged into master, so I imagine it'll be released with v0.12.2.) Theoretically, you could then do something like this to make the `<h1>` fade in on mount:

**JS**

```
...
<ReactTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true}>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</ReactTransitionGroup>
...
```

**CSS**

```
.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Got the same info too ;) Next release then!

Answer (score 7):

I looked into the *issue* a little deeper. With the current version of ReactJS it seems not possible to make an initial CSS transition. More info and thoughts [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2486).

Most probably things are gonna change with v0.13.x. You can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/addons/transitions/ReactCSSTransitionGroup.js) which features a **transitionAppear** *prop*.

**EDIT**: I downloaded from GitHub the latest ReactJS ([v0.13.0 - alpha](https://github.com/facebook/react)) and built it. Everything now works accordingly if you make use of **transitionAppear** prop (is to be set true explicitly). Here below you'll find the updated CSS and JSX as well as the live example:

**CSS:**

```
.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**JSX for ReactJS v0.13.0 - alpha:**

```
/**@jsx React.DOM*/

var ReactTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ReactTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true}>
          <h1>Hello world</h1>      
      </ReactTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
```

**Live example**: http://codepen.io/lanceschi/pen/NPxoGV

Cheers,
L

Comment: Darn, you beat me to the punch. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> appear
>
> Normally a component is not transitioned if it is shown when the `<Transition>` component mounts. If you want to transition on the first mount set `appear` to `true`, and the component will transition in as soon as the `<Transition>` mounts.
>   [from react-transition-group Docs](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition/#Transition-prop-appear)

### Example of usage

JSX:

```
<TransitionGroup>
  <CSSTransition classNames="fade" appear={true} >
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

CSS:

```
.fade-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
  z-index: 1;
}
.fade-appear.fade-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

As of:

- React v16.6.3
- react-transition-group v2.5.1