# React CSSTransitionGroup: Component not disappearing as planned

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to make a content window that is clickable. Upon click, the window will change. I would like the content on screen to fade out and the new content to fade in. So far, I have the fade in done (I think). The fade out won't work as planned. The components get pushed down the screen and disappear without even fading afterwards. I can upload a live version if need be to GitHub pages.

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385184/react-component-and-csstransitiongroup) and I'm not sure if it's the React version that's messing things up. I wanna say it's not?

Anyways, here's the render function of the main window:

```
  render: function() {
    if (this.state.window == 'main-window') {
      var result = 
        <div key={'main'} className='contentWindow'>
          <PortalBox portalType={'dev'} handleClick={this.changeToDev}/>
          <PortalBox portalType={'personal'} handleClick={this.changeToPersonal}/>
        </div>;
    } else if (this.state.window == 'dev-window') {
      var result = <DevWindow key={'dev'} handleClick={this.changeToMain}/>;
    } else {
      var result = <PersonalWindow key={'personal'} handleClick={this.changeToMain}/>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Greetings brands={this.props.brands}/>
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={1000} transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}>
          {result}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.contentWindow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
}

.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear .example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter .example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  /*transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;*/
}

.example-leave {
/*  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;*/
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave .example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  /*transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;*/
}
```

When I uncomment the visibility stuff under .example-leave, I make one of the two panel disappear but not both.

I'm following this [guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html).

Any ideas? Should I try to do the visibility stuff to make both panels disappear? Or should I try a completely different approach? Thank you!